# Isotrivial factors of Jacobian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, positive-characteristic

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of positive characteristic that it is not the algebraic closure of a finite field. Fix a smooth proper $k$-curve $C$ and write $J_C$ for its Jacobian abelian variety.

Assume that one of the isogeny factors of $J_C$ is isogenous to an isotrivial abelian variety. Is it true that $J_C$ has a factor isogenous to an isotrivial Jacobian?

Comment: I believe that this is false.  Denote $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ by $\kappa$.  Over $\mathbb{P}^1_\kappa$, there are families of supersingular, non-isotrivial Abelian varieties, cf. this answer by Ariyan Javanpeykar: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200919/abelian-varieties-with-good-reduction-everywhere-over-function-fields  Let $\mathcal{A}\to \mathbb{P}^1_\kappa$ be such a family.  Now let $B_0$ be a fixed supersingular Abelian variety.  Form the family $B_0\times_\kappa \mathcal{A}\to \mathbb{P}^1_\kappa$.  Now form a family of quotients of these by $\alpha_p$ subgroups in fibers.

Comment: I don't think so. If you start with a constant abelian variety $A/\mathbb{F}_q$ which is not isogenous to a jacobian and take a non-trivial one parameter family of curves in $A$ (cut $A$ in some projective space by a pencil of linear subvarieties of the right dimension) then you get a curve over $\mathbb{F}_q(t)$ whose Jacobian has $A$ as factor. I don't have a proof but I expect generically there will be no other factor which is a Jacobian or even isotrivial.

Comment: I see from Felipe Voloch's comment that I was missing the hypothesis that the family arise from Jacobians.  I thought the question was just asking, "if there is an isotrivial factor after an isogeny, is there a factor of the Abelian variety that is isotrivial?"  Reading the question again, I suspect that the OP is not asking whether the factor can be defined only after an isogeny.  I see, from Felipe's comment, that the question is whether the isotrivial factor (after isogeny) is itself isogenous to a Jacobian.

Comment: @Emiliano Ambrosi: Please define "isotrivial".

Comment: @JasonStarr.  "the question is whether the isotrivial factor (after isogeny) is itself isogenous to a Jacobian". Almost, I'm asking something, a priori, weaker, i.e. I'm asking if there is a factor isogenous to an isotrivial Jacobian, not necessarly the isotrivial factor we start with.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly. I say that a variety $X$ over $k$ is isotrivial if there exists a variety $X_0$ over a finite field $F_0$ such that 
$X\times_k \overline k=X_0\times_{F_0} \overline k$

Comment: Is it known whether or not any abelian variety over the algebraic closure of a finite field is isogenous to a Jacobian? This was an open question, perhaps attributed to Katz, some years ago but it might have been resolved by now. (The same question over a number field has been resolved by Tsimerman.)

Comment: @ulrich It is a conjecture of Oort that there should be abelian varieties not isogenous to jacobians for $g>9$. It is still open. Of course, the answer to OP's question depends very much on which way this conjecture goes. See this paper for a recent discussion of Oort's conjecture: https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.03552

Comment: @FelipeVoloch: Thanks for the reference!

Comment: @FelipeVoloch If I understand correctly, assuming Oort's conjecture we should be able to construct a counterexample. Thank you for your answer!